# how to fire scheduled task manually

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-batch

i want to execute scheduled task only if i need not automatically

```
   import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
    import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    @RestController
    @EnableScheduling
    public class RunScheduler {
        @Autowired
        private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

        @Autowired
        private Job job;

        @RequestMapping("collector/test")
        @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
        public void run() {

            try {

                String dateParam = new Date().toString();
                JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("date", dateParam).toJobParameters();

                System.out.println(dateParam);

                JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
                System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

i have tried with quartz but i get many error caused by the autowired annotations,
how to do

Comment: And what is the error?  Please provide the stack trace.

Comment: do you mean you want to start(not execute) a schedule task manually? i.e. till you call collector/test the scheduled task should not start. Once you called this endpoint, it should run every 5 seconds. Is this the requirement?

Comment: the problem is when i execute my springboot app the scheduled task start to run automatically
i want to run the scheduled task only if i call the collector/test

Answer (score -3):

Remove the @Scheduled annotation from the run method. This annotation causes the method to be invoked periodically.

Now as you want to execute the scheduled task manually, use the quartz scheduler API or its spring wrappers and get the full control of when to invoke the task.

Comment: This is not helpful. he wants to invoke the task manually if needed while preserving the current schedule.